# Cannot define constexpr pointer with constexpr int variable

Tags: c++, pointers, constexpr

```
int main() {
  constexpr int i = 5;
  constexpr const int *p = &i;
  return 0;
}
```

After compile the code above with:

```
g++ main.cpp
```

Here is the error:

> main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:                                     ║
> ~   ║main.cpp:3:28: error: ‘& i’ is not a constant expression                ║
> ~   ║    3 |   constexpr const int *p = &i;                                  ║
> ~   ║      |                            ^~                                   ║
> ~   ║                                                                        ║

Here is my g++ version:

```
    ║Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu                                             ║  
    ║Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,a║
~   ║da,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++,d --enable-bootstrap --prefix=/usr --libd║
~   ║ir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr║
~   ║/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --with-build-confi║
~   ║g=bootstrap-lto --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --with-system-zlib --enable║
~   ║-__cxa_atexit --enable-cet=auto --enable-checking=release --enable-cloca║
~   ║le=gnu --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp --enable-gnu-indirect-f║
~   ║unction --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-libstdcxx-backtrace --enable║  
~   ║-link-serialization=1 --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-mul║  
~   ║tilib --enable-plugin --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --disable-l║  
~   ║ibssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-werror                          ║  
~   ║Thread model: posix                                                     ║  
~   ║Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd                         ║  
~   ║gcc version 12.2.0 (GCC)
```

I just put a **static** keyword before the **i** as suggestion from IDE and it works, but I really don't understand why.

Comment: The address of a variable on the stack is not a compile time constant expression. Making it static enables to pin the address since it is no longer on the stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`constexpr` doesn't change the storage duration of a variable. Your `i` is still a local variable with automatic storage duration that lives until the end of the block in which it is defined and each call to the function has a new instance of the variable `i` (although all of these instances have the same constant value).

Which of these instances should the *compile-time constant* value of `p` refer to? It is impossible to decide, so a pointer to an automatic storage duration variable is not allowed to be the result of a constant expression.

`static` gives the variable static storage duration. There is then only one instance of `i` during the whole program duration and so it is clear what object the compile-time constant value of `p` would refer to. So this is allowed. In fact, because your initializer of `p` does not actually read the *value* of `i`, `i` doesn't need to be `constexpr` for this.